# How to initiate my exe file from administrative command prompt

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have logged in with one user in my system. Like, userA. Now, I have opened command prompt window with administrator privileges. In same Administrator command prompt window need to run my EXE file for userA without the password.

I have tried "RunAs" command but it will ask for Password.

Is there any other alternative, where I can solve my problem.

Comment: I am a little confused by your description, but if you are asking how to run a process as a different user without knowing their password, then I don't believe Windows allows this as it would be a massive security risk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have logged in with one user in my system. Like, userA.

Ok...

> In same Administrator command prompt window need to run my EXE file for userA without the password.

So you are already logged in as userA why would you need to enter the passsword again?

If you need to run something as as a different user you can create a batch file and set up a scheduled task to run it with their credentials, but don't actually give it a schedule. When you are then logged in as a differnt user you can call the scheduled task and it will run as the user it is associated with.